# How do I arrange flow control in TPL Dataflows?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm trying to get my head around controlling dataflow in TPL Dataflow. I have a very fast producer, and a very slow consumer. (My real code is more complex, but none the less, this is a pretty good model and it reproduces the problem.)

When I run it, the code starts drinking memory like it's going out of style--and the output queue on the producer fills up as fast as it can. What I'd really prefer to see is the Producer stop running for a while, until the Consumer has a chance to ask for it. From my readings of the documentation, this is what is supposed to happen: that is, I thought that the producer waits until the consumer has space.

This isn't the case, clearly. How do I fix it so that the queue doesn't go crazy?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
using System.Threading;

namespace MemoryLeakTestCase
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var CreateData = new TransformManyBlock<int, string>(ignore =>
            {
                return Enumerable.Range(0, 1000 * 1000 * 1000).Select((s,i) => "Hello, World " + i);
            });

            var ParseFile = new TransformManyBlock<string, string>(fileContent =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                return Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select((sst, iii) => "Hello, " + iii);
            }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { BoundedCapacity = 1000 }
            );

            var EndOfTheLine = new ActionBlock<object>(f =>
                {
                });


            var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true, };
            CreateData.LinkTo(ParseFile, linkOptions);
            ParseFile.LinkTo(EndOfTheLine, linkOptions);

            Task t = new Task(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("CreateData: " + Report(CreateData));
                    Console.WriteLine("ParseData:  " + Report(ParseFile));
                    Console.WriteLine("NullTarget: " +  EndOfTheLine.InputCount );
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }

            });
            t.Start();

            CreateData.SendAsync(0);
            CreateData.Complete();

            EndOfTheLine.Completion.Wait();
        }

        public static string Report<T, U>(TransformManyBlock<T, U> block)
        {
            return String.Format("INPUT: {0}   OUTPUT: {1} ", block.InputCount.ToString().PadLeft(10, ' '), block.OutputCount.ToString().PadLeft(10, ' '));
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried lowering the `BoundedCapacity` on `ParseFile` to something a little smaller like maybe 10 just to make sure it works?

Comment: Lois, good thought. I have tried that; it keeps the queue on `CreateData` even bigger. The major challenge I'm trying to solve here is how to make sure that `CreateData` pauses when the `ParseFile` queue is too big (or when its own output queue is too big).

Comment: For an alternative `TransformManyBlock` implementation that is output bounded and supports all `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions`, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994544/tpl-dataflow-block-consumes-all-available-memory/62385415#62385415).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, what you would do in a situation like this is to also set `BoundedCapacity` of the `CreateData` block. But that won't work here, because `TransformManyBlock` doesn't seem to take `BoundedCapacity` into account when filling the output queue from a single `IEnumerable`.

What you can do instead is to create a function that iterates the collection and uses `SendAsync()` to send more data only when the target can accept them:

```
/// <remarks>
/// If iterating data throws an exception, the target block is faulted
/// and the returned Task completes successfully.
/// 
/// Depending on the usage, this might or might not be what you want.
/// </remarks>
public static async Task SendAllAsync<T>(
    this ITargetBlock<T> target, IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            await target.SendAsync(item);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        target.Fault(e);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000 * 1000 * 1000).Select((s,i) => "Hello, World " + i);
await ParseFile.SendAllAsync(data);
ParseFile.Complete();
```

If you still wanted to have `CreateData` block that would behave similarly to your original code, you could have two bounded `BufferBlock`s, `SendAllAsync()` between them and then use `Encapsulate()` to make them look like one block:

```
/// <remarks>
/// boundedCapacity represents the capacity of the input queue
/// and the output queue separately, not their total.
/// </remarks>
public static IPropagatorBlock<TInput, TOutput>
    CreateBoundedTransformManyBlock<TInput, TOutput>(
    Func<TInput, IEnumerable<TOutput>> transform, int boundedCapacity)
{
    var input = new BufferBlock<TInput>(
        new DataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = boundedCapacity });
    var output = new BufferBlock<TOutput>(
        new DataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = boundedCapacity });

    Task.Run(
        async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                while (await input.OutputAvailableAsync())
                {
                    var data = transform(await input.ReceiveAsync());

                    await output.SendAllAsync(data);
                }

                output.Complete();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ((IDataflowBlock)input).Fault(e);
                ((IDataflowBlock)output).Fault(e);
            }
        });

    return DataflowBlock.Encapsulate(input, output);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response! That seems to solve the immediate problem, I think, although I'm still puzzling my way through your code. In particular, this model makes things happen in batch mode--I get a `boundedCapacity` worth of data once, then it pours out. Then a new `boundedCapacity`. And so on. I'd rather see, if it was possible, each unit sent individually.

Comment: And, to articulate a little on @svick's comment: It turns out that TransformMany only checks queues BETWEEN input entries; in order to make this scenario work, I would need to check WITHIN an entry.