# TransformBlock posting to output

Tags: .net, tpl-dataflow

My scenario is that I have a `BufferBlock<Stream>` receiving `Stream`'s from an external source, let's say the file system or some FTP server. These file `Stream`s will pass into another block and undergo processing.

The only catch is that some of these files are zipped, and I would like to add a `Block` in the middle which would unzip files when necessary, and create multiple output `Stream`'s for each of its entries.

However I do not want to use `TransformBlockMany`, because this means I have to fully receive the ZIP `Stream` and create the output `Stream` array at once.

I would want this `Block` to receive the ZIP `Stream`, start decompressing , and `Push` to the next stream whenever an Entry is ready, so the Process Block can start processing as soon as the first file is decompressed, and not wait until everything is decompressed.

How would I go around doing this?

Comment: What library are you using for ZIP decompression?

Comment: Using System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.

Comment: So far I understand that my problem is actually the async part. If I wouldn't use async, I might just use yield return in the TransformManyBlock. But I can't use yield return together with async.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to have any dataflow block type send multiple intermediate results as a result of a single input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62335850/is-it-possible-to-have-any-dataflow-block-type-send-multiple-intermediate-result). As a side note, in case you need to restrict the memory usage, be aware that the output queue of the built-in `TransformManyBlock` is unbounded. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994544/tpl-dataflow-block-consumes-all-available-memory) is a related topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood my problem is not being able to use an `yield` / `async` together . But after refactoring it , I got rid of that need, and came up with the following (simplified) version:

```cs
var block = new TransformManyBlock<Stream, Stream>((input) => {
var archive = new System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive(input, System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode.Read, true);
foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entry.Name)) //is a folder
        continue;

    yield return entry.Open();

}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the intermediate block for your unzip logic with [predicate linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604564.aspx) the blocks so you can check is stream an archive or not, something like this:

```
var buffer = new BufferBlock<Stream>();
var unzipper = new TransformManyBlock<Stream, Stream>(input => { /* unzip here */ });
var processBlock = new ActionBlock<Stream>(input => { /* process streams here */ });

buffer.LinkTo(unzipper, input => /* check is stream a zip archive */);
unzipper.LinkTo(processBlock);
buffer.LinkTo(processBlock);
```

As for `async` usage together with `yield`, you may give a try to the `AsyncEnumerable` package available on [GitHub](https://github.com/tyrotoxin/AsyncEnumerable) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncEnumerator/).